# How to internationalize string in coffeescript with i18n value?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, internationalization, rails-i18n

My problem is fairly simple: I have a string in one of my coffeescripts that I need to internationalize with an i18n value in my Rails application. Here's my code:

```
 $ ->
      $("#order_accepted_terms").on 'invalid', ->
        this.setCustomValidity('Die AGB müssen akzeptiert werden.')
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use this gem - https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js. It behaves much like native Rails I18n. After configuring the gem (check the readme at github) you add to the end of your layout (example is in Haml)

```
  = javascript_tag do
    I18n.defaultLocale = "#{I18n.default_locale}"
    I18n.locale = "#{I18n.locale}"
```

to set default and current locales and then you can use I18n in javascript (and coffeescript) as follows (some examples from the readme):

```
I18n.t("some.scoped.translation")
I18n.l("time.formats.short", "2009-09-18 23:12:43")
```

Also passing parameters to translations is supported. Considering you have a translation

```
en:
  users:
    greet: "Hello %{name}!"
```

you can do this

```
I18n.t("users.greet", {name: 'Nick'})
```

and you'll get as a result

```
Hello Nick!
```

You'll find much more examples following the link above.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a better way (and one that doesn't require yet another gem, remember - performance) is to include an object with internationalized messages as a global scoped javascript variable. So you'd go about it this way (for Ruby on Rails): 
 1. in your application.html.erb add  tags right after title (before any other javascript files are referenced)
 2. add a global scope variable object within those inline script tags in head

```
generalMessages = {
    someMessage: '<%= t 'path.to.some_message_in_yml' %>',
    anotherMessage: '<%= t 'path.another_message' %>'
}
```

3. reference the variable (in javascript/coffeescript/typescript) as:

```
foo = generalMessages.someMessage
```

Voila.

A similar approach (just different syntax how to reference and print out the internationalized messages, obviously) will also work for any other language that supports internationalization and has no way to add those internationalized strings directly in javascript.

Comment: Or `'path.to.some_message_in_yml': '<%= t 'path.to.some_message_in_yml' %>',`

Comment: Yeah that also works if you want to keep the exact same path to reference it. But that would mean you cannot use the dot notation to access the string - eg. you'd have to do something like `generalMessages['path.to.some_message_in_yml']` instead of `generalMessage.path.to.some_message_in_yml` or `generalMessage.shorthand.some_message_in_yml`.. It depends on coding style, of course, both versions are valid :) I prefer the dot notation and as I only need a small subset of messages in my JS, I don't necessarily always have the same path to access a message in JS as I do in yml.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for javascript based i18n library. You can check [i18next](http://i18next.com/) out. It's good for me.